# How would the travel ban pressure Iran

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, iran

I think that Trump wants to Pressure Iran by using the travel ban.

What kind of pressure is the Travel ban expected to put on Iran?

Comment: Please include some research to at least frame a topic and then make the question answerable objectively.

Comment: http://www.voanews.com/a/ninth-circuit-court-of-appeals-trump-travel-ban/3716762.html

Comment: Trump has claimed the ban is to "protect" US citizens, and he does not use the ban specifically to place pressure on Iran.

Comment: It would pressure them to start building nuclear technology even faster. It would pressure them to work with North Korea even more.

Comment: Once the "pressure" here is determined, I would be curious to know how it compares to *Kentucky Fried Chicken's* typical pressure of their chicken pressure cookers.

Comment: The official reason is that Trump doesn't want dangerous terrorists born in the Iran to enter the USA.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when a country put restrictions for other countries, it's all about politics. With the case of Iran, Donald Trump executed the [Executive Order (EO) 13769](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/01/27/executive-order-protecting-nation-foreign-terrorist-entry-united-states) with one purpose: keep american safe (from terrorist attacks), according to his staff and supporters. This argument doesn't make sense because Iran is not the author of any kind of terrorism inside United States, contradicting the main objective of the actions taken by President Donald Trump. In fact, the latest terror attacks were [made by US born citizen](https://www.newamerica.org/in-depth/terrorism-in-america/) as explained in the chart above:

[image: Terrorism inside United States]

The most cited case in order to support the EO about Iran is the measures taken in 1980 during the US Embassy hostage crisis but again, what Jimmy Carter did when banned Iranians was more political than prevent terrorism. So what the Trump administration wanted to do is send a message, a political message. The ban is the perfect argument for Iran to destroy the *Iran deal* and continuing the nuclear program since the EO [violates the terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_nuclear_deal_framework#Summary_of_agreement) and agreements made during the Obama Administration.

Comment: *with one purpose: keep american safe.* do you have any thing to back this statement up?  Also terrorism is not the only way that a country can be a threat to the US.  This  whole answer is a [Straw Man arguement](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/straw-man.html) so far as I can tell

Comment: During his campaign Trump [promised to keep american safe](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/01/31/opinions/trump-immigration-order-stewart/) and during the presentation of the EO, that's the speech used by his staff and supporters. And I never said in the answer (as you can see) that terrorism is the only threat, what I'm doing is answer the question about Iran, which has a ban made by the EO mentioned in the answer and  it is called PROTECTING THE NATION FROM **FOREIGN TERRORIST** ENTRY INTO THE UNITED STATES

Comment: Then you should explain that better in your answer.

Comment: I already mentioned the EO but I uptdated the answer